# Can Gravity Forms be integrated with CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, civicrm

We have a site that has 5 different Gravity Forms currently.  They work great and we love them.   We're planning on setting up CiviCRM for this organization in WordPress and want to know if its possible to map all the data from our current forms directly into CiviCRM.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the community effort i think has gone in to Caldera Forms but there is a product for GF at https://shop.civivip.com/civi-plugins/gravity-forms-integration/ but I am sure you would have already found that from the simplest of google searches so am thinking you may be asking something that is less obvious.

Also in case you didn't spot it, i recommend you steer Civi question via http://civicrm.stackexchange.com as it gets many more civi eyeballs (though i appreciate this question is aimed at both audiences.)

Comment: would have been helpful to have cross referenced your Question to https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34684/can-gravity-forms-be-integrated-with-civicrm since you asked it there too